# Binary approach of affinity propagation

Tags: cluster-analysis, bayesian-networks, belief-propagation

I'm implementing the [Binary Variable Model for Affinity Propagation](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/pubs2/2009/NC09%20-%20SimpleAP.pdf) and have a conceptual doubt about it.

I can understand most of the algorithm and have my implementation working, but I don't understand why is not needed to send both values for the messages and why after adding incoming messages positive values correspond to one and negative to zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An explanation can be found at [Frey and Dueck 2007](http://www.psi.toronto.edu/affinitypropagation/FreyDueckScience07.pdf)